# LASTools QGIS clip not working

Tags: qgis, clip, lidar, lastools

As I am trying to clip the LiDAR data (.las) file from shapefile (.shp)

I have used the lastools(lasclip) to clip the .las file from area of interest that is shapefile from QGIS plugin but it didn't work it is creating the
output file but it is not clipping that area of interest.
[image]

After running the tool I am getting this output which is same as input LAS.

[image]

Is there are any different method to cut LiDAR data with polygon?

Comment: CloudCompare makes that operation easy. I haven't had much luck with LASTools in QGIS.

Comment: Do both layers have the same CRS?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of, which is what just happened to me right now is that the coordinate systems are different between the two layers. Depending on where you get your point cloud data from, it may be a very specific regional projection system, whereas you working projection system may just be a generic WGS 84.

Answer (score 0):

the projected coordinate systems must be the same when clipping. Do you check them?